# How do I add the "- Any -" option for the published status on exposed filters?

Tags: views, 8

I need to add the *- Any -* option for the published status, on exposed filters.

[image]

I can't use it, as when I try to add it, I get the following error.

> You must select a value unless this is an non-required exposed filter.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I add *- Any -* as option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the screenshot shows, the filter is set as *Required*. This means the users need to select a value for that filter that, being a filter for the published status, can only get *Yes* and *No* as values.

If you want to allow users to select *- Any -* as value for that filter (which isn't really a value for the published status, but a value that tells the view not to filter the nodes basing on their published status), you need to deselect the checkbox that is shown to the left of *Required*.

> [image: screenshot]